# MySQL JSON store string with \/

Tags: php, mysql, json

please I have problem with storing JSON string in MySQL.
I need store this:

```
{"image_intro":"images\/tips\/test.png","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}
```

but I get error in PHP:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'image_intro' (T_STRING) in /xxx/xxx/test.php on line 124
```

How I can get string into DB please? Thank you!

inseert code:

```
function setImage($image, $id) {
    $tourId = $id;
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fm_content WHERE id_tour = '$tourId' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_fetch_array($check) == true) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE fm_content SET images = '{"image_intro":"images\/tipy\/velikonoce.png","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}' WHERE id_tour = '$tourId'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Well show your PHP code that attempts to store it

Comment: Where is your insert query?

Comment: Could you please provide your source code? Try using MySQLi, this will likely fix your problem

Comment: code added, ok I will try MySQLi

Comment: use $json_data = serialize($json_data);

Comment: This is not MySQL error, it's `PHP Parse error`

Comment: Even StackOverflow shows you the error with the syntax highlighter. You're not escaping quotes!

Comment: @Julian how does this relate to MySQLi ?

Comment: @Raptor you wouldn't have to care about escaping. But now I see his source code and understand whats wrong, it was just a guess

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
function setImage($image, $id) {
    $tourId = $id;
    $check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fm_content WHERE id_tour = '$tourId' LIMIT 1");
    if(mysql_fetch_array($check) == true) {
        $data = '{"image_intro":"images\/tipy\/velikonoce.png","float_intro":"","image_intro_alt":"","image_intro_caption":"","image_fulltext":"","float_fulltext":"","image_fulltext_alt":"","image_fulltext_caption":""}';
        mysql_query("UPDATE fm_content SET images = '{$data}' WHERE id_tour = '$tourId'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Working, but there is in image_intro: "images/tips/test.png" but I need "images\/tips\/test.png"

Comment: Now tried withour \/ only with / and with Joomla works too! Thanks!

Comment: @Desttro please learn how to escape PHP strings. It's one of the basics of PHP